# Bootbox modals don't format HTML properly

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using bootbox for my website's pop-up modals. When the function below is called, I want to display a small table with some information.

```
function infoModal(){
    var table = "<div>" + "<table class='formattedTable'>" + "<thead>" + "<tr>Legend</tr>" + "</thead>" + "<tbody>" + "<tr class='catString'>This color is the first color.</tr>" + "<tr class='warn'>This color is the second color.</tr>" + "<tr class='caution'>This color is the third color.</tr>" + "<tr class='danger'>This color is the fourth color.</tr>" + "</tbody>" + "</table>" +"</div>";
    bootbox.confirm({
        message: table,
        buttons: {
                confirm: {
                    label: 'OK'
                }
        },
        callback: function (result) {
            if (result) {
                console.log("Thanks for using this modal!");
            }
        }
    });

}
```

However, when I test it out in HTML, it's formatted like this:

```
<div class="bootbox-body">
 <div>LegendThis color is the first color.This color is the second color.This color is the third color.This color is the fourth color.

    <table class="formattedTable">
        <thead><tr></tr></thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="catString"></tr>
            <tr class="warn"></tr>
            <tr class="caution"></tr>
            <tr class="danger"></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I know that I didn't place the divs (minus the `bootbox-body` div) like that in my `table` variable above, so what's happening here?

Comment: You're forgetting the `td`'s

Comment: Whoops, you're absolutely correct! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured it out -- I forgot the `<td>` tags that go into each row! This is what the function should look like:

```
function infoModal(){
    var table = "<div>" + "<table class='formattedTable'>" + "<thead>" + "<tr><td>Legend</td></tr>" + "</thead>" + "<tbody>" + "<tr class='catString'><td>This color is the first color.</td></tr>" + "<tr class='warn'><td>This color is the second color.</td></tr>" + "<tr class='caution'><td>This color is the third color.</td></tr>" + "<tr class='danger'><td>This color is the fourth color./<td></tr>" + "</tbody>" + "</table>" +"</div>";
    bootbox.confirm({
        message: table,
        buttons: {
                confirm: {
                    label: 'OK'
                }
        },
        callback: function (result) {
            if (result) {
                console.log("Thanks for using this modal!");
            }
        }
    });

}
```